# HTC Trophy not detected

Tags: 11.04, usb, devices

When I plug in the device via USB chord, nothing happens and the device is not shown on the desktop. However, when I type "lsusb" into a terminal this is the output:

```
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b249 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:04ec Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I'm assuming Microsoft Corp. is the device but why isn't Ubuntu displaying it on the desktop?

Comment: I don't think 'Microsoft Corp.' is your HTC device. My HTC appears as 'High Tech Computer Corp. Desire' (For an HTC Desire)

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Go into your phone's settings and make sure the "Connect to PC" is set to "Disk Drive."

Answer (score 1):

lsusb is a good idea.  i would check dmesg's tail too.  That way you know for sure.  Then once you're sure, if it IS detected and it doesn't mount, then it just isn't seen as a usb storage device.

If you need some functionality that isn't present for a USB device on the linux side, you can install windows in a virtualbox VM and enable USB passthrough.  USB passthrough isn't available in the open source edition as far as I know.  For that reason you have to install it with the binary installer from the Oracle website to get to a fully functioning USB passthrough setup.

The guys on FreeBSD evidently reversed the USB passthrough component and got something working for Virtualbox OSE.  Maybe someone will port their adaptation to linux one day.

Comment: Thanks but how come when I plug it in and run VirtualBox with Windows XP it still isn't detected? I will open Zune and it still says "no devices connected".

Comment: With USB passthrough enabled(Oracle vbox not open source vbox) and the appropriate device selected to be "passed through".  I doubt this is the case...

Comment: I have Oracle Virtual Box I didn't know there was another "vbox".

Comment: There's Virtualbox OSE and Oracle Virtualbox.  OSE is installed with apt-get, the other is installed with a binary installer...

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that HTC sense is installed, and that you dont have USB Debugging enabled on your phone. If that dosent work, check the phone's screen when you plug it in, it should have multiple options e.g "Charging only, Mount as Mass storage/Hard Disk, IPsec Pass through ect". If it dosent, you may have a problem with the phones script not running for when it is attached to a computer. Also check that it isnt just the cable. Hope this helped you
References: I root and unlock androids and iPhones, so im fluent in android SDK and OS